# init-open-recentf with use-package

Tags: init-file, use-package, recentf

I want to use `use-package` for nearly everything in my `init.el`.
I have set up `recentf`. And to make the recent-file buffer pop up when Emacs starts I also included the `init-open-recentf` package.

But I cannot make it work with `use-package`. The `recentf-list` does not pop up on start.

This question is not only about how to make it work but more about how to make it work the `use-package` way.

This is the problematic `init.el`

```lisp
    (use-package recentf
      :bind
      ("C-x C-r" . recentf-open-files)
      :config
      (setq recentf-max-menu-items 15
            recentf-max-saved-items 100
       )
      (recentf-mode 1))
    
    (use-package init-open-recentf
      :after recentf
      :config (init-open-recentf))
```

Of course I can call `init-oopen-recentf` outside the `use-package` thing. But I assume there is a way to do this with `use-package`.

```lisp
    (use-package init-open-recentf
      :after recentf)
    ;; works
    (init-open-recentf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet isn't working because `recentf` won't load until you press the `C-x C-r` key combination, which in turn implies `init-open-recentf` will not be loaded. You can read more about [lazy loading with `use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#notes-about-lazy-loading).

```
(use-package recentf
      :bind ("C-x C-r" . recentf-open-files)
      :config
      (setq recentf-max-menu-items 15
            recentf-max-saved-items 100
       )
      :hook (after-init . recentf-mode))
    
(use-package init-open-recentf
      :after recentf
      :config (init-open-recentf))
```

This works for me. The hook ensures that `recentf-mode` is loaded and configured after Emacs starts. It is possible to come up with alternate forms using `:init` sections.

You will need to add `:demand t` to the second `use-package` macro if you have set `use-package-always-defer` to a non-nil value.

Comment: My snippet does work. Maybe my direct `(init-open-recentf)` does invoke loading of `init-open-recentf` package which itself loads `recentf` because of `after: recentf` directive. But thanks. Your hook is a more use-package like way what I also asked for.

Comment: Why not using `:defer nil` instead of that hook? IMHO this means "load imidiatly" or doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, not deferring and using `(recentf-mode 1)` in the `:config` section should also work. I like hooks because they allow you to explicitly control when you want to do things.

Comment: Note that `init-open-recentf` loads `recentf` because of the `(require 'recentf)` line in the `init-open-recentf.el` code, and not because of the `:after recentf`.